# Generate a date vector using <ctime>

Tags: c++, datetime, c++17

How can I build a vector containing all dates (daily period) between two given dates using `<ctime>` library?  For example, given January 1, 2019 and January 10, 2019, a vector containing the 10 dates in between (inclusive)?

I don’t really mind about the representation of the dates, could be a string or any other structure but I would like to understand how to manipulate `<ctime>` objects.

If there is a better library for time representation in C++, I’d be glad to hear about it.

Comment: How are the dates formatted? `<ctime>` has 4 time-related types - is it one of those, or is it defined some other way?

Comment: @NickReed what do you mean by four types? Four representations ?

Comment: `ctime` includes `clock_t`, `size_t`, `time_t`, and `struct tm` - were you planning to store the dates in one of these?

Comment: @NickReed yes, but I don’t know how to properly generate a date range

Comment: Can you provide an example of c++ code that has the start date and end date stored in two variables? At present it's unclear how the data will be stored, so it's had to say how a range can be generated.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @NickReed I’d like to use struct tm as a date object and get an array of struct tm

Comment: I cannot fully understand the phrase "a vector of dates (with a daily period) given two dates".  An example may help me understand.

Comment: @L.F. Given two dates means for example 1 Jan 2019 and 10 Jan 2019 will give me a vector containing the 10 dates between (and including) those 2.

Comment: @eliaroseX I understand it now.  If you [edit] your question to include this information, other people will understand as well.

Comment: @L.F. Done, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the C++20 date library (a.k.a. [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)):

```
#include "date.h"

auto get_dates(date::sys_days first, date::sys_days last)
{
    std::vector<date::sys_days> dates;
    for (; first <= last; first += date::days{1})
        dates.push_back(first);
    return dates;
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L8MwjzSSC3fXXrMd))

Comment: This is much easier than mucking about with `tm`s.  Once more standard libraries implement this, this should be how you write this code.

Comment: @MarshallClow Yeah, with the ranges library it is even better.

Comment: Well heck, if I had known `<ctime>` wasn't required I could've posted this. :-) (upvoted)

Comment: @HowardHinnant my bad, I wanted to use <ctime> but this solution is quite interesting

Comment: <chuckle> I'm delighted you find it interesting.  Just let me know if you have any questions about how to use it.

Comment: great code! great library!
How can I get with this a vector from "2020-01-01 00:00:00.000" to "2020-01-20 23:59:59:999"?

Comment: @Paul with `using namespace date;`, you can use `get_dates(January/1/2020, January/20/2020)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small, quick demo program - it makes a vector of `struct tm`, and then prints the time out. Each new entry to the vector is one day ahead of the old one, seamlessly wrapping around months and years as it rolls past them.

Time is often stored in a `time_t`, which is the count of seconds since y2k. This data type seems easier to manipulate than a `struct tm` - we'll use it, coupled with how many seconds are in a day, to create a vector of `struct tm` as we go. We'll start at time0, and we'll continue 20 days, to time19, adding a new `struct tm` for every day we count.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {

  double secs_in_a_day = 86400;


  time_t time0; //your start time here
  time(&time0); //i'm using the current time

  //20 days later
  time_t time19 = time0 + (20 * secs_in_a_day); //your end time here

  std::vector<struct tm > timevec;

  for(time_t i = time0; i <= time19; i += secs_in_a_day) {
    struct tm t = *(gmtime(&i));
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    timevec.push_back(t);
  }

  char buffer[80];

  for(struct tm tim : timevec) {
    strftime(buffer, 80, "Time: %d / %m / %y\n", &tim);
    puts(buffer);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Note that the for loop increments by the number of seconds in a day. It's likely possible to do this directly with `struct tm` or `struct tm *` variables, but then there would be a good deal of chasing pointers around. Given that it's so easy to convert to `time_t`, it's probably worth saving the headache to use it instead.

Hope this helps - C++ admittedly leaves a bit to be desired when dealing with time.